# HTML onClick VS jQuery mousedown Timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, mousedown

I'm working with legacy HTML pages written ~10 years ago. That being said, it should be explicitly known that refactoring old code is not only NOT time effective, but also a risky endeavor.

A legacy webpage has many buttons which activate JavaScript event(s) using the onClick="myFunction()" tag. I've been tasked with interfacing a JavaScript file (which uses jQuery) into these legacy webpages. I've added the JavaScript file in question and jQuery 1.9.1 source and attached them to the legacy HTML pages prior to the closing body tag, ex:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

This JavaScript source file (which uses jQuery) activates a mousedown event on the buttons with the attached class "getStats", ex:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.getStats', function (event) {
    //Stuff
});
```

However, when the jQuery activates, it does NOT perform the redirect the button is supposed to do through the HTML onClick event.

I can't find any information online on how the HTML onClick and jQuery mousedown event timings happen to understand whether or not I'm encountering a race condition. Both the HTML onClick redirect and jQuery mousedown events need to happen, and I can't just simply go back and edit all the legacy HTML onClick events to be done in jQuery either as that would take months of work.

Sample jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/koa2hsbp/

The jQuery works right off the bat. If you comment out the jQuery mousedown function, then the HTML onClick works. But I have to make it to where both parts activate (preferably jQuery mousedown prior to HTML onClick), without changing the HTML's functionality. (Again, changing the legacy code is a costly endeavor in and of itself.)

Comment: In your example, the events propagate fine. It's the `alert()` that is interrupting the propagation to the click handler. Edit: Watch your console: https://jsfiddle.net/koa2hsbp/1/

Comment: @Antiga is almost right - alert do the trick, but it is not about stopping propagation - click event simply never trigger, as it never happen with alert.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation about events:
mousedown - triggered immediately after mouse button pushed down while focusing element.
mouseup - triggered immediately after mouse button goes up while focusing element
click - triggered when you have consecutive mousedown+mouse up on the same element.

So in your example - you push mouse down and this immediately triggers code which produce alert. Then you release mouse button, but web paged is focused on alert, not on our element as alert window by nature blocks everything else and interrupt javascript. Since there is no mouseup event - there is no click event as well, so legacy code is not invoked.

Try following to prove I am right - push mouse down and hold it. Then click enter button - this will remove alert. Then release mouse button while on top of element. This will trigger click.

Unfortunately it is hard to mix mousedown click and alert in same example. Consider moving jQuery handler to click if you need alerts. That of cause will invoke jQuery after legacy handler.